# Will this design for an XHP70.2 LED Driver with arduino control work to the params specified?

Tags: arduino, i2c, current-source, led-driver

I am making a driver PCB to drive an XHP70.2 LED at 15A (~7v) Continuous, Controlled from an Arduino. I am new to OpAmp's so I would like to know:

- Does this circuit look as though it would function as intended (as a
  current source for 15A@7v from a 2S Li-ion, controlled by an Arduino
  PWM pin)?
- Would 1.5mOhm (1W 2512 [6432 Metric] Thick Film) be a suitable value
  for RSENSE?
- What OpAmp would be best?
- What values would be needed for R1, R2,...R8? (& C1)
- Would (CSD16340Q3)'s be suitable for U1 & U2?

CSD16340Q3 - http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/csd16340q3.pdf

NCP3420 - https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCP3420-D.PDF

LTC6992 - https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6992-1-6992-2-6992-3-6992-4.pdf

If it will work, are there any possible improvements? i.e. reducing the number of components

[image: Diagram of Circuit Plan]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute some common-mode and differential voltages.

I use 50mV for max current to choose the current sensor.  For smaller power you might be able to use say 20 or 25 mV FS but your R ratios need to be low error 0.5% or better have matched gain ratio arrays for high CMRR noise rejection.  Note: Very layout sensitive for high gain. And logic loops on schematic need to be physically as small as possible with stray inductance and high gain. (~100~200)

Then use R4/R2=R3/R1 for gain.  Check Vcm min~max to make the inputs within Rail-to-Rail or else move the sensor to the ground side of the load and choose any dual PNP input Op-Amp to sense near 0V.

The next stage might use equal R values for unity gain.

Comment: Thanks. This answer has been a lot of help.